# can someone help me build a usb jig to force android device into recovery

Tags: usb, debugging, android, mobile

Years ago i bricked a phone trying to install a ROM not designed for that phone. As a result the phone went into a bootloop and would not go into recovery mode. Researching the problem i found a solution that required me to build what was described as a USB JIG. The jig was made by cutting the micro usb plug from a phone charger and soldering resitors between the positive and negative wires on the cord, whereby creating what ill term closed circuit and basicaly shorting the phone out to a specific resistance. It gave me the specific resistance and i was able to build the jig and force the phone into recovery mode. Worked great. I now have a tablet in much the same condition and am unable to connect via adb.
ive not been able to find the same information as before and im not an electritian, nor am i educated in that field. I am educated in following directions though and hope that someone educated in this field can explain for me the basics of the process ive described and help me to recreate the previous effect with the current tablet.

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2013/11/17/getting-a-shell-on-any-android-device/

Comment: Thank you I'm going to look into this